# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, conda, spacy, rasa-core

i try to set things for rasacore in my system when i run the command

> python3 -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_config.yml --data data/nlu.md -o models --fixed_model_name nlu --project current --verbose

after it tries to get

> rasa_nlu.utils.spacy_utils  - Trying to load spacy model with name 'en'
>   it gives error as
>   File "E:\anaconda\envs\botenv\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 119, in load_model
>       raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
>   OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: Post config.yml pls

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment.

Comment: language: "en"
pipeline: "pretrained_embeddings_spacy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and link the spacy model you want to use. 
e.g.

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en
```

Also, preconfigured pipelines will be deprecated, see the new [guide to choosing a pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/#a-longer-answer) and pass the components you want explicitly

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U spacy==2.1.3
```

downgrading spacy works for me

[ChatterBot error- OSError: [E941] Can't find model 'en'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66087475/chatterbot-error-oserror-e941-cant-find-model-en)

maybe, model 'en' is renamed in spacy 3.