# ChatterBot error- OSError: [E941] Can't find model 'en'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, spacy, chatterbot

I tried running my first Chatterbot program (its from the PyPi page of Chatterbot), and when I run it, I get an error. The error is related to Spacy, but I am unable to find a solution.

Here is the code:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

chatbot.get_response("Hello, how are you today?")
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/users/USER/desktop/bot.py", line 77, in <module>
    chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 21, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 47, in load
    return util.load_model(name, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 328, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name]))
OSError: [E941] Can't find model 'en'. It looks like you're trying to load a model from a shortcut, which is deprecated as of spaCy v3.0. To load the model, use its full name instead:

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

For more details on the available models, see the models directory: https://spacy.io/models. If you want to create a blank model, use spacy.blank: nlp = spacy.blank("en")
```

It would be helpful if someone finds a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: One of the possible solutions is to downgrade `spacy` to a version 2.x, like `pip install -U spacy==2.1.3`

Comment: You may need to do `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` before using it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you actually have the right spacy model installed. For example, install `en_core_web_sm` with the `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command in the terminal.

Next, fix this error:

```
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

That is,

1. Open the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py` file
2. Go to Line 13
3. Replace `self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())` with

```py
if self.language.ISO_639_1.lower() == 'en':
    self.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
else:
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

You will need to add more conditions for other languages you need to support.

Comment: Gracias gran ayuda!

Comment: @EzequielMiceli De nada!

Answer (score 4):

Check the version of spacy you are using.

Install spacy and download the language model, *en_core_web_sm*, in this case using

```
 python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

If it is v3.0, you will need to load it using

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

If it is < v3.0, you can link the model creating a shortcut using

```
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en
```

and thus load it using `nlp = spacy.load("en")`

Comment: I'm still having this same issue. I think the best thing to do [as of time of writing] is to downgrade to a lower version of spacy (maybe to version `2.1.3`). Then redownload `en_core_web_sm` by using this command `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`. This should give you `en_core_web_sm==2.1.0` and then you can apply the linking (i.e `python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en`)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other comments, please be aware of an issue with SpaCy 3.0.3 and Python 3.8 - if these are the versions you're using, you may have to download the language model via Python shell, ex.:

```
import spacy
from spacy.cli.download import download
download(model="en_core_web_sm")
```

For these versions, downloading via `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` may result in exceptions - as described ex. [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/explosion/spaCy/7160/783289407).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download en_core_web_sm by running: python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

You need to modify the following code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zWNn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try just install the spacy with >>pip install -U spacy

And change the code

```
self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

in "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py" to

```
  if self.language.ISO_639_1.lower() == 'en':
     self.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
  else:
    self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

Get work for me here and I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For **Linux** and **Mac** users :

To the above top-voted answer I will add that the location of `tagging.py` is :

`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot`

To be more precise :

`<Install_path_of_Python>/site-packages/chatterbot`

( *The install path could be your virtual environment path as well* )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try just install the spacy with `pip install -U spacy`

And change the code

```
self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py` to

```
if self.language.ISO_639_1.lower() == 'en':
   self.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
else:
  self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

if downloading the package doesn't work as follows:

> python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

then you don't need to change the code in the package, just change the cause.

> from chatterbot import languages
>
> languages.ENG.ISO_639_1 = "en_core_web_sm"

it will change "en" to "en_core_web_sm" for spacy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually have the right spacy model installed. For example, install `en_core_web_sm` with the `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command in the terminal.

Next, fix this error:

```
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 13, in __init__

> `self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())`
```

That is,

1. Open the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py` file
2. Go to Line 13
3. Replace

   ```
   self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
   ```

   with

   ```py
   if self.language.ISO_639_1.lower() == 'en':
       self.nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
   else:
       self.nlp = spacy.load(self.language.ISO_639_1.lower())
   ```

You will need to add more conditions for other languages you need to support.

It is working for me, I recommended this!